# API design choice regarding implementating the internal layer from security and usability perspective

Tags: c++

**1.**

```
class Socket
{
public:
    class Impl;

    Impl& impl();
    const Impl& impl() const;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

class Socket::Impl
{
public:
    struct Internal
    {
        typedef SOCKET Type;

        Type i;
    };

    Internal internal() const;

private:
    Internal m_internal;
};
```

**2.**

```
class Socket
{
public:
    class Impl;
    struct Internal;

    Impl& impl();
    const Impl& impl() const;

    Internal internal() const; // return m_impl->internal();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

struct Socket::Internal
{
    typedef SOCKET Type;

    Type i;
};

class Socket::Impl
{
public:
    Internal internal() const;

private:
    Internal m_internal;
};
```

The headers for Impl and Internal are completely hidden of the end user. Which one of these makes more sense to you?

**My own thoughts.**

**1.**
The only hint that the public header gives is that the class has been implemented using the pimpl-idiom. Since the internal layer of classes often need to access the `Internal` type of other classes, there is the disadvantage of having to first call `impl()` and then `internal()`.

**2.**
It additionally hints that it has some kind of internal structure. For the internal layer it is easier to get the `Internal` type, without having to call impl() first. But it seems semantically wrong since `Internal` is actually internally used for `Impl`, not `Socket`.

And additional question, is there a technique to use some advanced pimpl technique so that the public header has no data members at all? Maybe I am overthinking security, but I would like to avoid cases where the raw memory of Socket is accessed and then some kind of mess could be created by overwriting bytes.

Comment: Should have posted this here instead? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I'm not sure.. What do you mean by `I would like to avoid cases where the raw memory of Socket is accessed and then some kind of mess could be created by overwriting bytes`?

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames, Socket s; char* data = (char*)&s; [mess up m_impl];